# Tensorflow: What to expect from LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, autoencoder, attention-model

I build a neural net, which is capable of "translating" different date formats to a german date format, so for example:

```
x -> 26/04/1992; y -> 26.04.1992
```

I am using an Encoder - Decoder Architecture with an LSTM and Attention Layer.
With this settup, I reach about 98.4% Accuracy. My question is, which accuracy can I expect?

Since this is an issue, where I would expect 100% accuracy after some training time, I only reach up to 98.4%. So can I expect perfection from such a model, so it is worth my time to keep looking for improving it, or am I missing something in my understanding?

In an update version of the model, the model also has to learn different languages input, also written out text. For example:

```
x -> Freitag, 28. Juli 2620; y -> 28.07.2620
```

or

```
x -> 28.07.2620 ; y -> Freitag, 28. Juli 2620
```

What I could inspect so far is, that the model has problems with identifying, which day of week belongs to which date.
(Wrong) Predictions like:

```
x -> 28.07.2620 ; y -> Mittwoch, 28. Juli 2620
```

are common. Is there a way of fixing that and thus to improve the performance?
Thanks!

Comment: I should add: Generating more train data with excel does not improve the model significantly. The improvement of having 3x data is very small.

Comment: As machine learning algorithms predicts/forecasts a value for a given input. There will always be an error linked. Accuracy 100% is a myth so to say. What I am trying to say that it would not perform similar to any date converting algorithm which is rule based.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! 
I updated my question to specify what I am looking into.
What is your opinion, when training should be stopped because no further improvement can be seen?